# use c++ to detect USB drive and copy files from USB to C:/

Tags: c++, copy, usb

Trying to use C++ to detect USB drive (this part works) and then copy files from USB Drive to C:.  I have tried passing variable to string using several different variations but no luck. Using recycled code from previous response but still not able to copy files from USB to C: after DRIVE_REMOVABLE detected. Anyone have any ideas?

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    WCHAR myDrives[105];
    WCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD serialNumber, maxComponentLen, fileSystemFlags;
    UINT driveType;

    if (!GetLogicalDriveStringsW(ARRAYSIZE(myDrives) - 1, myDrives))
    {
        wprintf(L"GetLogicalDrives() failed with error code: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        wprintf(L"This machine has the following logical drives:\n");

        for (LPWSTR drive = myDrives; *drive != 0; drive += 4)
        {
            driveType = GetDriveTypeW(drive);
            wprintf(L"Drive %s is type %d - ", drive, driveType);

            switch (driveType)
            {
            case DRIVE_UNKNOWN:
                wprintf(L"Cannot be determined!");
                break;
            case DRIVE_NO_ROOT_DIR:
                wprintf(L"Invalid root path/Not available.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_REMOVABLE:
                wprintf(L"Removable.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_FIXED:
                wprintf(L"Fixed.");
                break;
            case DRIVE_REMOTE:
                wprintf(L"Network.");
                break;
            default:
                wprintf(L"Unknown value!");
            }
        }
    }
```

After further investigation I realized the problem was not in my code per se, but in the device itself.  The issue involves computers with Symantec Endpoint Protection.  I can insert USB drive and right click, copy and paste folders all day long but when I run the following code,  it does nothing.  Also the following code works on devices that don't have Symantec Endpoint.
I have tried this:

```
fs::path source5 = "F:\\Install files";
            fs::path targetParent5 = "C:/";
            auto target5 = targetParent5 / source5.filename(); 
            try
            {
                fs::create_directories(target5); 
                fs::copy(source5, target5, fs::copy_options::recursive);
            }
            catch (std::exception& e) 
            {
                std::cout << e.what();
            }
```

And have tried:

```
std::ifstream src("F:\\Install files", std::ios::binary);
            std::ofstream dst("C:\\", std::ios::binary);
            dst << src.rdbuf();
```

All have worked on a device without Symantec but I can still manually copy on Symantec devices.  Need a way to read and verify USB.

Comment: Well, at what point do you attempt to copy files?

Comment: I tried using filesystem to copy after case DRIVE_REMOVABLE.  It works to copy if I put whatever volume (D:, E:, etc) manually but I need it to do so no matter what volume letter it picks up.  I will use on multiple computers so it may pick up a different volume each time.  It looks like I would have to pass the 'drive' variable as a string in order to copy files but I tried several instances and couldn't get it to work.

Comment: Can you show us your attempts (successful/manual and failed) at calling the filesystem copy? Maybe you need to remove/replace a backslash character, or some such?

Comment: Added additional information.  Still no change.

Answer (score 0):

The issue was a group policy.  Once that was resolved, the solution now works. Below is what works for me:

```
#include<iostream>
#include<tchar.h>
#include<Windows.h>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    WCHAR myDrives[105];
    WCHAR volumeName[MAX_PATH];
    WCHAR fileSystemName[MAX_PATH];
    DWORD serialNumber, maxComponentLen, fileSystemFlags;
    UINT driveType;

    if (!GetLogicalDriveStringsW(ARRAYSIZE(myDrives) - 1, myDrives))
    {
        wprintf(L"GetLogicalDrives() failed with error code: %lu\n", GetLastError());
    }
    else
    {
        for (LPWSTR drive = myDrives; *drive != 0; drive += 4)
        {
            driveType = GetDriveTypeW(drive);
            if (driveType == DRIVE_REMOVABLE) {
                wprintf(L"\nUSB Drive detected in drive %s\n", drive);
            }
           
        }
    }
}
```